# How to convert chinese characters to hexadecimal in java

Tags: java

I want to convert unicode characters which have code values in 2 byte, 3 byte range to hexadecimal.

I know how to convert characters to hexadecimal. For which, I am first converting characters to ascii by casting using int. And from that i convert to hexadecimal using Integer.tohexString.

However, I am not sure how to deal with unicode characters like chinese, etc. Can someone help?

Comment: Don't "convert to ASCII"; Java `char` is big enough to support the entire [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), which should contain CJK Han script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not handle the String as an array of bytes in Java... But if you want, you can use `getBytes()`

```
byte[] bs = "中文".getBytes("utf-8");
for(byte b : bs)
    System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b) + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275031/how-to-convert-chinese-characters-to-hexadecimal-in-java/12275230#comment16461788_12275031).

> Don't "convert to ASCII"; Java `char` is big enough to support the entire [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), which should contain CJK Han script.

```
/* 七 -> 4e03 */
assert "4e03".equals(Integer.toHexString('七'));
```

Comment: may I please know the reason as to why shouldn't I convert it to ASCII...as to what are the complications that arise.

Comment: @JannatArora ASCII is a very limited character set that only supports 128 characters.

Comment: @JannatArora if you want to support 3- and 4-byte UTF-16 code points you should use `String.charAt`, which properly handles surrogates (hence why it's `int` not `char`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to rethink your approach.

In general, it sounds like you want to do some sort of I/O of this data. In general, you do that with character encodings and the java.io Reader/Writer API.

See InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter.

You can always send the output of a writer to a FileOutputStream (or ByteArrayOutputStream for that matter) to get the characters out as binary data.

```
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file"), "utf-8"));
out.println("...");
```

If you want to then base64 encode that data or just represent it as ascii hex, that is a pretty simple thing.